# can I bundle multiple installs for Mac OSX and do them as a single script?

Tags: macos, installation

I have a lot of open source software to be installed for a course.  We currently run on PCs that we provide.  If we allow students to use their own Macs in Mac-centric schools, that means we have to load the software on those Macs.

Rathern than have to load individual software, is there any way I can create a single file, mount it and run a script to install all packages?
We are willing to simplify the installs by standardizing the locations to store the applications, since the students will have identical machines.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can do this.

Mac is a unix operating system and comes with the Bash shell installed. Once you have determined the steps necessary to install your software you can put all those steps into a bash script. This file can be made executable so your students can just double click to install.

If you want a nicer experience with more options, you should use PackageManager to create a package that install things in a nice GUI way. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I have never drilled down on mac osx packages, but this isn't a matter of writing a shell script.  Each package, when clicked, asks for the password of the user when asking for permission to install.

Comment: Well if you want specific help with specific software, it would be good to provide more specific information.